# Chef 12.0.3: Why I can't find my own provider on Resource Collection?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

I wrote my own provider which runs ok, for example:

```rb
my_custom_provider "#{node['ipaddress']}" do
    my_attribute_1 node['ipaddress']
    action :create
end

template '/opt/app/something.conf' do
  mode '0664'
  owner 'someuser'
  group 'someuser'
  notyfies :restart, "my_custom_provider[#{node['ipaddress']}]", :delayed
end
```

I receiving error (under `chef-solo` in `Vagrant`):

```
ERROR: resource template[/opt/app/something.conf] is configured to notify
resource my_custom_provider[10.0.2.15] with action restart, but 
my_custom_provider[10.0.2.15] cannot be found in the resource collection.
template[/opt/app/something.conf] is defined in 
/tmp/vagrant-chef/2a59b2477390af49acec413909d80cf5/cookbooks/project/recipes/default.rb:76:in `from_file'
```

But when I reverse direction of notification it works fine:

```rb
my_custom_provider "#{node['ipaddress']}" do
    my_attribute_1 node['ipaddress']
    action :create
    subscribes :restart, 'template[/opt/app/something.conf]', :delayed
end

template '/opt/app/something.conf' do
  mode '0664'
  owner 'someuser'
  group 'someuser'
end
```

I think this is a bug in `chef-solo` run under `vagrant` or maybe I can't add my custom providers as notification target ?

Comment: There's no warning before ? Could you share your LWRP or HWRP code ?

Answer (score 0):

To get notifications working on your custom LWRPs, you might want to look at the example here in chef docs https://docs.chef.io/lwrp_custom_provider.html#updated-by-last-action